# Laravel Eloquent: count($result) vs $result->count()

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent

I'm a bit new to this, and was originally trying to check if my model was returning results with `isEmpty()`, but thought I'd try `count()` instead, then I came across the following:

I've got the following code, which returns data from my model:

`$results = Game::where('code', '=', $code)->with('genre', 'creator')`

And whether I use `first()` or `get()` combined with `count(result)` or `$results->count()` I get different values, and I'm not sure why.

when using `->first()`

```
dd($results->count()) = 11930 // Number of rows in the db
```

when using `->get()`

```
dd($results->count()) = 1 // What I'd expect the query to return
```

when using `->first()`

```
dd(count($results)) = "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"
```

when using `->get()`

```
dd(count($results)) = 1
```

I don't understand 1) why when using first, the count is the same as every row in the db. 2) Why `count()` can't be used with `first()`.

Is anyone able to shed some light as to why I can't use count on first as I'd like to?

**Update:**

I'm also not able to use `->isEmpty()` with `->first()` but can with `->get()`...?

When I try using it with first, I get `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty does not exist.`

Comment: You're doing it wrong

Comment: @WahyuKristianto Thanks for your useful insight!

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure why your database count and your results count aren't the same, however I can shed some light on the different types of count.

```php
Game::where('code', '=', $code)->count();
```

This is being called on a query builder instance. It is run on the database query, without selecting all the rows. Check out the title **Aggregates** here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

```php
Game::where('code', '=', $code)->get()->count();
```

As soon as your use `get()` laravel selects the rows, boots them all as models, and creates a collection. This count is on the collection (a bit like an array) so just gets the number that are returned (i.e. if they are paginated or anything like that it will just get that amount). Check out **Count** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-count).

```php
Game::where('code', '=', $code)->first()->count();
```

This is being run on the first returned model... unless you've written it, a default laravel model won't have a `count()` method.

```php
count($results)
```

Finally, `count()` when not a class method is just the default php function that returns the length of an array or other object ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)).

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

`get()` returns collection of objects while `first()` returns modal object of query.

```php
$results = Game::where('code', '=', $code)->with('genre', 'creator')

dd($results->count()) = 11930 // Number of rows in the db
```

when using `->get()`

```php
$results = Game::where('code', '=', $code)->with('genre', 'creator')->get()
dd($results->count()) = 1
```

because it has collection, which contains numbers of objects of database data. As `->count` getting only one collection so it returns `1`.